# edge corners are not sharp with canny filter

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, contour, shapes, edge-detection

I am trying to detect edges from an image using Canny filter. I have been able to detect the images but the corners are not very sharp (highlighted in red circles). Surprisingly, the first corner is sharp and not burned out compared to other corners. Why this is happening and how it can be avoided ??

Please have a look at the attached image.[image]

My code:

> edges = cv2.Canny(image,0,255)

I have not applied any blurring as it makes the corners worse. Moreover, the change of min and max values for Canny also does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Beyond applying blurring as mentioned, the Canny algorithm is designed to thin the edge. By starting with a binary image, you aren't operating within the assumptions that Canny is built on.

If your images are known to be binary, you could find the edge you're looking for by [eroding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb) the image and then subtracting from the original. In addition to providing you with your expected result, it may be faster as well.

C++ used to generate image:

```
auto image = cv::imread("binary.png", -1);
cv::Mat eroded_image, edge_image;

cv::erode(image, eroded_image, cv::Mat());

edge_image = image - eroded_image;
```

Or python as described in [OpenCV's tutorial page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) (kernel size edited):

```
kernel = numpy.ones((3,3), numpyp.uint8)
eroded_image = cv2.erode(image, kernel)
```

[image: Original image]
[image]

You can also use the morphological gradient described in the same tutorial, which is basically the same operation, but subtracting from the dilated image instead of the original. This will provide a thicker edge, but it may be considered more "correct" because it is centered around the increase in intensity.

Answer (score 0):

The Canny algorithm includes Gaussian smoothing, which would slightly affect the gradient in your corners.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector

If you know that all of your images are going to be noise-free images like the sample one you've provided, you should consider taking the Laplacian of the image.

Comment: even with laplacian the edge corners are not sharp

Comment: The edges in the image, if you zoom in, are not hard edges, but rather they are gradient edges.  If your edges are multiple pixels wide, then there's no guarantee, as far as I know, to get perfectly crisp corners.  You could threshold the image to just black and white to get rid of the gradual edges.